# How to delete brackets and text within them python

Tags: python-3.x

I am generating a text file the contents looks like this

```
[AnyTextOrNumber]AnyTextOrNumber#AnyNumber
```

How can I generate the file so it always looks like this

```
AnyTextOrNumber#AnyNumber
```

I just want to get the text file generated without the brackets and contents within them

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Actually try to write some code, and we might be able to help troubleshoot issues you have with it.

Comment: The code I have gets text from an image in the format above and makes a text file with the generated code. Sometimes the code has leading brackets with letters or numbers in them I am asking for help on how to process the text in the text file to not have the leading Brackets and their contents.... so if someone can explain to me how to do that with sub() id appreciate it.

Comment: I would recommend to have a look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html there are many tutorials on regular expressions around.

Comment: @BillyFReally You can mark the answer of your choice as accepted if they helped you with your query.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re` to achieve the desired result.

I've used two patterns and different string scenarios and their behavior.
You can see the limitations we can have and chose whichever suits your purpose the best.
You could use something like this :

```py
import re

str1 = "[AnyTextOrNumber]AnyTextOrNumber#AnyNumber"
str2 = "[AnyTextOrNumber]AnyTextOrNumber#AnyNumber[MoreTextOrNumber]"
str3 = "[AnyTextOr]Number]AnyTextOrNumber#AnyNumber"
str4 = "[AnyTextOr]Number]AnyTextOrNumber#AnyNumber[MoreTextOrNumber]"

pattern1 = r'\[[^()]*\]'
pattern2 = r'\[.*?\]'

convPattern1_str1 = re.sub(pattern1, '', str1)
convPattern1_str2 = re.sub(pattern1, '', str2)
convPattern1_str3 = re.sub(pattern1, '', str3)
convPattern1_str4 = re.sub(pattern1, '', str4)

convPattern2_str1 = re.sub(pattern2, '', str1)
convPattern2_str2 = re.sub(pattern2, '', str2)
convPattern2_str3 = re.sub(pattern2, '', str3)
convPattern2_str4 = re.sub(pattern2, '', str4)

print(convPattern1_str1) #Will give AnyTextOrNumber#AnyNumber
print(convPattern1_str2) #Will remove everything
print(convPattern1_str3) #Will give AnyTextOrNumber#AnyNumber
print(convPattern1_str4) #Will remove everything

print(convPattern2_str1) #Will give AnyTextOrNumber#AnyNumber
print(convPattern2_str2) #Will give AnyTextOrNumber#AnyNumber
print(convPattern2_str3) #Will give Number]AnyTextOrNumber#AnyNumber
print(convPattern2_str4) ##Will give Number]AnyTextOrNumber#AnyNumber
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you could do it with [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slicing):

```
input_file = "file_input.txt"
output_file = "file_output.txt"

# Open 2 files, 1 for reading, 1 for writing
with open(input_file, "r") as in_file, open(output_file, "w") as out_file:
    for row in in_file:
        # Remove newlines
        row = row.strip()
        # find "#"
        number_index = row.find("#")
        # slice from string
        any_number = row[number_index:]
        # find "]" and slice
        string_index = row.find("]")
        any_string = row[1:string_index]
        # Format new line and write to file
        out_file.write(f"{any_string}{any_number}\n")
```